# Get-ADComputer does not find hostname but I can find it manually

Tags: powershell, hostname

So I have a script that has worked forever and I have never bat an eye at it. However out of nowhere it has stopped working. When I try to search for hostnames in AD by using the Get-ADComputer cmdlet, it returns the following error message:

**Get-ADComputer : Cannot find an object with identity: 'hostname' under: 'DC=domain,DC=name,DC=edu'**

Even if I try a basic `Get-ADComputer hostname` it returns the same error message. However if I pull up AD myself and search for the hostname I find it just fine. There seems to be some sort of disconnect between AD and Powershell.

Anyone else ran into this where basic PS cmdlet's won't work properly?

Comment: What is the `SamAccountName` of the computer you found using ADUC? This works for me, BTW.

Comment: `Get-ADComputer -Identity` works for me.

Comment: ```Get-ADComputer -Identity hostname``` does not work for me. Still receive the error but I can open up the AD gui myself and search the exact same hostname and find it.

Comment: Are you working in an AD forest (with child domains) or is it just one? What happens if you query the AD using parameter `-filter "name -like '*$hostname*'"`?

Comment: Negative, just one. If I do the ```-filter 'name -like "*$hostname*"'``` it will find the computer. However if I try that within my script, it still won't find it but won't return any error messages

```[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [string]$ComputerName
)

echo ""
echo ""

$Properties =
@(
 'CanonicalName',
 'Enabled',
 'Created',
 'LastLogonDate',
 'IPv4Address',
 'OperatingSystem',
 'OperatingSystemServicePack',
 'OperatingSystemVersion'
)
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "*$ComputerName*"' -Properties $Properties | select $Properties```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had `"$ComputerName"` when it should have been `$ComputerName` no quotes. Not sure why I need to search for something "like" the computername rather than the name itself, but it works. Final script looks something like:

````
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [string]$ComputerName
)

echo ""
echo ""

$Properties =
@(
 'CanonicalName',
 'Enabled',
 'Created',
 'LastLogonDate',
 'IPv4Address',
 'OperatingSystem',
 'OperatingSystemServicePack',
 'OperatingSystemVersion'
)
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like $ComputerName' -Properties $Properties | select $Properties```
````